# Configure Skinr 7.x grid settings

Tags: theming

How can I define the width of the grid of a block using skinr?

I've used skinr in Fusion, now I'm trying to configure it with Skeleton theme.
I've installed Skinr 7.x-2.0-beta1, and enabled all of its modules, but I can only add css classes.
[image]

See this other window
[image]